# Facebook API: How to get User's ad account ids?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-permissions

So I'm trying to authenticate users via Facebook to access their ad accounts id (for ad management). I've checked that I have been granted permissions via the first ajax request.

**Issue**: Currently I'm using `react-facebook-login` package to authenticate users and the response i'm getting includes `name, email, picture, userID`

**Attempt**: I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to access user's ad account ids via given `userID`? Or is there a better endpoint I can use.

Current approach using `react-facebook-login`

```
import React from "react";
import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login";

class FacebookAuth extends React.Component {
  responseFacebook(response) {
    console.log("result --> ", response);

    fetch(
      "http://graph.facebook.com/yyy/permissions?access_token=xxx"
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log("permissions ==>", res);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookLogin
        appId="xxx"
        autoLoad={true}
        fields="name,email,picture, birthday"
        scope="email, ads_read"
        callback={this.responseFacebook}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default FacebookAuth;
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adaccounts/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to call the endpoint `me/adaccounts`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "account_id": "xxx",
      "id": "act_xxx"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "yyy",
      "id": "act_yyy"
    },
 ]
}
```

That will return AdAccounts the user can access ([See the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adaccounts/) for further fields)